# WebView Methods is not called in android

Tags: android, methods, webview

My Web view is not calling the javascript function it is returning warning like below. Can anybody suggest how to get rid of the below warning.

`07-30 10:15:44.031: W/webview_proxy(3770): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'WebViewCoreThread'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.`

Below is my function.

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v){
    System.out.println("dfdsf");
    // Tell the javascript to handle this if not in selection mode
    //if(!this.isInSelectionMode()){
        this.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        this.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        this.loadUrl("javascript:android.selection.longTouch();");
        mScrolling = true;
        //this.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //}


    // Don't let the webview handle it
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning is telling you everything. You are calling the webview methods directly. That means you are calling them on WebViewCoreThread. You have to call them on the UI Thread that means in the Activity which uses this webview.

Like:

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(id);
wv.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
wv.setPluginsEnabled(true);
wv.loadUrl("javascript:android.selection.longTouch();");
```

Comment: Is it same thing in the problem that if I called any WebView methods in AsyncTask, then it will not work?

Comment: This is accepted answer and I cant see setJavaScriptEnabled() or other these methods for WebView instance.

Comment: I guess you are on a newer version of Android. This post was published on Android 2.3.3 i think. I'm not sure at all. In the newer versions you have to use the following code: `wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`. Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 16):

As the warning says you are calling the webview methods in the `WebViewCoreThread`.
Thus modify your code like this,

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v){
    YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            this.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            this.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            this.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
            this.loadUrl("javascript:android.selection.longTouch();");
            mScrolling = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use This Code I thinks it will work for you,And modified it according to your need ##

```
    private WebView webView;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        webView.setInitialScale(1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");

    }

}
```

Comment: ok what about if I want to run javascript commands on the webview?

Answer (score 0):

onLongClick is a member of webview ?

It seems you can't call all WebView methods on thread 'WebViewCoreThread'.

You can use handler, send msg to handler in onLongClick , then call WebView methods in your handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must execute your code of onLongClick method in runOnUIThread() or using Handler, this warning is due to use all this on a worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can use WebView via Runnable. No Need to use Activity.

```
    webView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
          getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
          getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
          loadUrl("javascript:android.selection.longTouch();");
          mScrolling = true;
        }
    });
```