# android app crashing on webview url change

Tags: android, multithreading, url, webview, crash

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944347/webview-methods-is-not-called-in-android), but solutions are not working in mycase.

Android app is crashing when running function webview.loadUrl 
Getting the following error on close:

> E/AndroidRuntime(1593): Caused by:
>   java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread
>   'WebViewCoreThread'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI
>   thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other
>   threads.

EDIT: Trying now to run the function in runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ })  but getting errors and having trouble with where to enter runOnUiThread within context. 
Here is full code:

```
   public class MyJavaScriptInterface {  
         @JavascriptInterface 
             public void androidFieldPrompt(String title, String msg, final String funct) {  
                 final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);  
                 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);                 
                 alert.setTitle(title);  
                 alert.setMessage(msg);  
                 alert.setView(input);
                 alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {  
                        String value = input.getText().toString();  

                        // ERROR IS BEING THROWN HERE
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window."+funct+"('"+value+"')"); 

                        return;                  
                       }  
                    });  
                alert.show();        
             }
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebView Methods is not called in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944347/webview-methods-is-not-called-in-android)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> E/AndroidRuntime(1593): Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A
>   WebView method was called on thread 'WebViewCoreThread'. All WebView
>   methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView
>   may not support use on other threads.

As the error points out .. you are calling webview methods on non UI Thread (inside a click listener ).

you should use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to use main thread when calling web view method , inside onClick

```
  MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
       @Override
        public void run() {
           String value = input.getText().toString();
           webView.loadUrl("javascript:window."+funct+"('"+value+"')");
           return;
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use Runnable in order to use WebView on UI thread and eliminate the issue:

```
webView.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       String value = input.getText().toString();
       webView.loadUrl("javascript:window."+funct+"('"+value+"')");
    }
});
```

Comment: this is much neater because you dont need reference to an activity