# WebView may not support use on other threads with StartApp

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to integrate into my game startapp that changing from one activity to another exit publicity and advertising shows me correctly but when click on ad gives me the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called         on thread 'Thread-1082'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:1927)
at android.webkit.WebView.destroy(WebView.java:641)
at com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity$6.run(Unknown Source)
at com.startapp.android.publish.d.l$a$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-1082'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:1918)
```

Does anyone know why it can be?

This is the code I use to open it:

```
startAppAd.showAd(new AdDisplayListener() 
            {

                public void adDisplayed(Ad arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void adHidden(Ad arg0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SeleccionarLigaActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("PrimeraVez", primeraVez);   
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            });
```

I have also tried with this:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startAppAd.showAd();
                    startAppAd.loadAd();
                }
            });
```

Now gives this error with 2.0.5:

```
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199): Activity com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@42571a48 that was originally bound here
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@42571a48 that was originally bound here
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:974)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:868)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1452)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1440)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:496)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.connectToEngine(TextToSpeech.java:685)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:655)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:608)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.webkit.AccessibilityInjector$TextToSpeechWrapper.<init>(AccessibilityInjector.java:682)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.webkit.AccessibilityInjector.addTtsApis(AccessibilityInjector.java:483)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.webkit.AccessibilityInjector.addAccessibilityApisIfNecessary(AccessibilityInjector.java:168)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.webkit.AccessibilityInjector.updateJavaScriptEnabled(AccessibilityInjector.java:418)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.updateJavaScriptEnabled(WebViewClassic.java:1682)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.webkit.WebSettingsClassic.setJavaScriptEnabled(WebSettingsClassic.java:1125)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at com.startapp.android.publish.d.m.a(Unknown Source)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity.a(Unknown Source)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity.a(Unknown Source)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity$b.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(Unknown Source)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:261)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:363)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-20 23:13:26.230: E/ActivityThread(23199):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  Method)
```

A greeting and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not in a new Thread,WebView should be used in UI Thread~

Or you can see the answer ~
[WebView Methods is not called in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944347/webview-methods-is-not-called-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I'm Miki from StartApp.

It seems like the issue you are experiencing is specific to your app, as we've never experienced it before. Therefore, it requires further investigation by our support team, which will need to check your specific app.
Please contact us through the developers portal or at support@startapp.com and provide as many details as possible which will help us reproduce the issue, along with your manifest file, the activity in which you've integrated our ad and link to your app in the play market/apk file.